# Google Visualization cluster multiple column stacks having goal lines

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

My goal is to cluster two or more column stacks having corresponding goal lines.

What is the best way to get this chart?

My initial thought was to use a `ComboChart`.  I can only accomplish a single stack bar with multiple lines.

I was able to try a 'bar' type chart (below snippet) and accomplished two clustered bar stacks using two axis but cannot get lines.  I also think this could be limiting in the future to only two stacks.

Any ideas??  Thanks as always!

```js
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Goal Line 1', 'Profit', 'Bonus', 'Goal Line 2'],
          ['2014', 1000, 400, 400, 200, 50, 500],
          ['2015', 1170, 460, 400, 250, 2000, 500],
          ['2016', 660, 1120, 400, 300, 10, 500],
          ['2017', 1030, 540, 400, 350, 15, 500]
        ]);

        var options = {

          bars: 'vertical',
          isStacked: true,
          series: {
            0: { targetAxisIndex: 1 },
            1: { targetAxisIndex: 1 },
            2: { targetAxisIndex: 1 }, //this should be a line 
            3: { targetAxisIndex: 2 },
            4: { targetAxisIndex: 2 },
            5: { targetAxisIndex: 2 } //this should be a line 
          },
          vAxes: {

          },

          height: 400,
          xcolors: ['#1b9e77', '#d95f02', '#7570b3']
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));


      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['bar']}]}"></script>
       <div id="chart_div"></div>
    <br/>
```

============UPDATE=============
So I've tried now a ColumnChart with two axis.   I can see that I get two stacks now but they are one in front of the other. You can see that the red/orange stack sticks out from behind the blue/purple stack.

Is it possible to offset stack 1 to the left and stack 2 to the right?  Then I think visually the chart could work for my application.

```js
      google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages': ['corechart']
      });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

      function drawVisualization() {
        // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Month', 'Ax1 line', 'Stack1 1', 'Stack1 2', 'Ax2 line', 'Stack2 1', 'Stack2 2'],
          ['2004/05', 10, 110, 210, 710, 810, 910],
          ['2005/06', 20, 120, 220, 720, 820, 920],
          ['2006/07', 30, 130, 230, 730, 830, 930],
          ['2007/08', 40, 140, 240, 740, 840, 940],
          ['2008/09', 50, 150, 250, 750, 850, 950]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
          vAxis: {
            title: 'Cups'
          },
          hAxis: {
            title: 'Month'
          },
          seriesType: 'bars',
          series: {
            0: { type: 'line', targetAxisIndex: 1},
            1: { type: 'bars', targetAxisIndex: 1},
           2: { type: 'bars', targetAxisIndex: 1},
            3: { type: 'line', targetAxisIndex: 2},   
            4: { type: 'bars', targetAxisIndex: 2},  
            5: { type: 'bars', targetAxisIndex: 2}
          },
          isStacked: true
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
       <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: not sure how to accomplish, _classic_ charts (`google.visualization.BarChart`) do not support multiple stacks, and _material_ charts (`google.charts.Bar`) do not support combo charts.

Comment: Wow...I stumped you??  I am surprised combo won't do this type of setup.  Could there be another framework which could work?

Comment: not sure, I know someone has asked this in the past, but I can't find the question.

Comment: Hi, I tried a ComboChart.  I think it could work if I knew how to set the bar offsets for stack 1 and stack 2.  Any thoughts?

Comment: there are no standard options  / methods you can apply to move the stack. but I have an idea. however, it will be difficult if you want to allow interactivity, such as hovering the bars to display the tooltips, etc. I'm assuming you want to allow interactivity?

Comment: At this point I only see two paths....  1) "roll your own" modifying Google with JavaScript or 2) learn a new framework which supports the chart type I need.  They are probably both involve the same amount of time/work.  What are your thoughts?

Comment: agreed, I'm close to having a solution for path 1 -- just trying to work out an issue with interactivity

Comment: You are the master!  I have learned a lot from your help over the last year.  I cannot say thank you enough!

Answer (score 0):

the problem here, *material* charts do not support combo charts (adding the line).
and *classic* charts do not support multiple stacks.

however, by adding a line series in between the columns series,
and moving one to another y-axis,
the stacks will become separated, though on top of one another.

on the chart's `'ready'` event, we can reduce the size of both stacks by half,
then move the second stack to the right.

the biggest problem here is on interactivity.
the chart will reset all the columns back to their original position on interactivity, such as hover.
as such, we must use a `MutationObserver` to prevent the reset.

however, there is still a couple minor issues I haven't worked out.

when you hover the first stack, the tooltip appears above the original position.
and there is a highlight surrounding the original position.

here is what I have so far...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', 'Ax1 line', 'Stack1 1', 'Stack1 2', 'Ax2 line', 'Stack2 1', 'Stack2 2'],
    ['2004/05', 10, 110, 210, 710, 810, 910],
    ['2005/06', 20, 120, 220, 720, 820, 920],
    ['2006/07', 30, 130, 230, 730, 830, 930],
    ['2007/08', 40, 140, 240, 740, 840, 940],
    ['2008/09', 50, 150, 250, 750, 850, 950]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Cups'
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Month'
    },
    seriesType: 'bars',
    series: {
      0: { type: 'line', targetAxisIndex: 0},
      1: { type: 'bars', targetAxisIndex: 0},
      2: { type: 'bars', targetAxisIndex: 0},
      3: { type: 'line', targetAxisIndex: 1},
      4: { type: 'bars', targetAxisIndex: 1},
      5: { type: 'bars', targetAxisIndex: 1}
    },
    isStacked: true,
    legend: {
      maxLines: 2,
      position: 'top'
    },
    tooltip: {
      target: 'both'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  var chartLayout;
  var chartBounds;
  var legendColors = [];
  var saveCoords = {};
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    // init chart elements
    chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    chartBounds = chartLayout.getChartAreaBoundingBox();
    var bars = chart.getContainer().getElementsByTagName('rect');

    // find legend markers
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(bars, function (bar) {
      var color = bar.getAttribute('fill');
      var xCoord = parseFloat(bar.getAttribute('x'));
      var yCoord = parseFloat(bar.getAttribute('y'));
      if ((xCoord >= chartBounds.left) && (yCoord < chartBounds.top) && (color !== '#ffffff')) {
        legendColors.push(color);
      }
    });

    // find bars
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(bars, function (bar, index) {
      var xCoord = parseFloat(bar.getAttribute('x'));
      var yCoord = parseFloat(bar.getAttribute('y'));
      if ((xCoord > chartBounds.left) && (yCoord > chartBounds.top)) {
        var color = bar.getAttribute('fill');
        var width = parseFloat(bar.getAttribute('width')) / 2;
        bar.setAttribute('width', width);
        saveCoords[xCoord + yCoord] = {
          width: width,
          x: xCoord
        };
        if (legendColors.indexOf(color) > 1) {
          bar.setAttribute('x', xCoord + width);
          saveCoords[xCoord + yCoord].x = xCoord + width;
          saveCoords[xCoord + width + yCoord] = saveCoords[xCoord + yCoord];
        }
      }
    });

    var observer = new MutationObserver(function () {
      // reset bars
      var bars = chart.getContainer().getElementsByTagName('rect');
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(bars, function (bar, index) {
        var xCoord = parseFloat(bar.getAttribute('x'));
        var yCoord = parseFloat(bar.getAttribute('y'));
        if ((xCoord > chartBounds.left) && (yCoord > chartBounds.top)) {
          var color = bar.getAttribute('fill');
          if (saveCoords.hasOwnProperty(xCoord + yCoord)) {
            bar.setAttribute('width', saveCoords[xCoord + yCoord].width);
            bar.setAttribute('x', saveCoords[xCoord + yCoord].x);
          }
        }
      });
    });
    observer.observe(chart.getContainer(), {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
  window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    chart.draw(data, options);
  });
});
```

```css
#chart_div {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Note: I also found an issue once posted here. For now, the legend must be fully displayed on one line. To run the example here, you must run the snippet, then click **Full page**.

Comment: hope this helps, I will try to correct the issues when I have time. if you don't hear back in a few days, you may need to remind me...