# Google Charts ComboChart with nonstacked bars, stacked bars and lines

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am having an Issue with Google Charts recently. I am trying to create a Combochart that shows Data for 25 consecutive years. For each year, I'd like to represent **two** bars, where one of them is stacked (combined of two data-values). In Addition to that, I'd like to create two dashed lines that indicate the average of the two bar-sets. In the end, I want to achieve a Result like in this given screenshot:
[Example-Chart. This is what it shoud look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XIpN.png)

So far, I've tried several combinations of options yet unable to achieve the correct solution. I can stack them all, or leave them all unstacked. I've tried a second vAxis, but the bars appear in front of / behind of each other and are therefore not visible (= they are overlapping). How can I achieve combining stacked and unstacked bars, and still be able to add horizontal lines to it?

Here in my Code, the numbers for the average-values are hardcoded right now (8000 and 7000), but this is not to be worried about.

```js
let data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Jahr');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Kosten ALT');
        data.addColumn('number', 'AfA');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Kosten NEU');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Ø ALT');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Ø NEU');
        let maxValue = 0;
        for(let i = 0; i < years.length; i++){
            data.addRow([[i+1].toString(), years[i].energy_costs_existent, years[i].repayment, years[i].community_tariff, 8000, 7000]);
            maxValue = Math.max(years[i].energy_costs_existent, maxValue);
        }

        let options = {
            isStacked: true,
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            chart: {
                title: 'Liquidität',
                subtitle: 'Aufwand p.A.'
            },
            vAxis: {
                viewWindow: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: maxValue*1.3
                }
            },
            seriesType: 'bars',
            series: {
                0: {
                    color: '#fe0609'
                },
                1: {
                    color: '#999999'
                },
                2:{
                    color: '#1ba65e'
                },
                3:{
                    type: 'line',
                    lineDashStyle: [2,2],
                    color: '#fe0609'
                },
                4:{
                    type: 'line',
                    lineDashStyle: [2,2],
                    color: '#1ba65e'
                },
            },
        };

        let chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            chartType: 'ComboChart',
            containerId: markup_id,
            dataTable: data,
            options: google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options)
        });
        //zoomChart is a function that allows me to click on a g-chart and get a zoomed-in
        //version in a popup. This is the reason, why I would need a ChartWrapper,
        //in case you were wondering
        this.zoomChart(chart, markup_id, 1.5);
        chart.draw();
```

Comment: the problem here is that only google's _material_ column chart allows multiple stacks. but at the same time, they do not support combo charts, so you can't add a line series. the _classic_ column chart supports combo charts, but does not allow multiple stacks. I was able to get close with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62290913/5090771) by making manual modifications, but there are still a few minor issues.