# Google Visualization Stacked Combo Chart with Dual Y Axis has bar stacks are overlapping

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a Combo Chart with dual Y axis.

Bolivia and Equador are stacked on`targetAxisIndex: 0.`

Madagascar and Ethiopia are also stacked on `targetAxisIndex: 1`.

Madagascar/Ethiopia stack (total 45) is overlapped in front of the Bolivia/Equador stack (total 25).

How can I get the two stacks side by side?   Bolivia/Equador is currently hidden behind Madagascar/Ethiopia.

Any hints are most appreciated!

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

      function drawVisualization() {
        // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Month', 'Bolivia', 'Ecuador', 'Madagascar',  'Ethiopia', 'Average'],
          ['2004/05',  10, 15, 20, 25, 18],
          ['2005/06',  10, 15, 20, 25, 18],
          ['2006/07',  10, 15, 20, 25, 18],
          ['2007/08',  10, 15, 20, 25, 18],
          ['2008/09',  10, 15, 20, 25, 18]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title : 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
          vAxis: {title: 'Cups'},
          hAxis: {title: 'Month'},
          seriesType: 'bars',
           vAxis: {
              viewWindow: {
                max: 35,
              }   
            },
          series: {
            0: {type: 'bar', targetAxisIndex: 0},
            1: {type: 'bar', targetAxisIndex: 0},
            2: {type: 'bar', targetAxisIndex: 1},
            3: {type: 'bar', targetAxisIndex: 1},
            4: {type: 'line',targetAxisIndex: 0},
          },
          isStacked: true
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

=========WORKING UPDATE==========================

**UPDATE1**

I've made great progress.  <s>With actual data points there is one more consideration.  Please run this data set and let me know how to get the all columns to reappear.  When I put real data in, I'm loosing the bars.</s>

FYI...Adding `focusTarget: 'category'` helps the tooltips.  It shows all values on a single hover.

**UPDATE2**

I've made some modifications to the code and can now see all the bars on the initial draw.  However the `mutationObserver` is not working properly now.  See snippet behavior.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

function drawVisualization() {
  // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', 'Made', 'PlanToMake', 'Delivered', 'PlanToDeliver', 'Goal'],
    ['2004/03', 10, 0, 10, 0, 10],
    ['2005/04', 8, 2, 8, 2, 10], //Crossover month
    ['2006/05', 0, 10, 0, 10, 10],
    ['2007/06', 0, 10, 0, 10, 10],
    ['2008/07', 0, 10, 0, 10, 10],
  ]);

  var options = {
    // title : 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Cups'
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Month'
    },
    seriesType: 'bars',
    legend: {
      position: "top",
    },
    hAxis: {
      slantedText: true,
      slantedTextAngle: 90
    },
    focusTarget: 'category', //IMPORTANT for tooltips to look resonable
    vAxis: {
      viewWindow: {
        max: 20,
      }
    },
    series: {
      0: {
        type: 'bar',
        targetAxisIndex: 0,
        color: "rgb(0, 86, 145)"
      },
      1: {
        type: 'bar',
        targetAxisIndex: 0,
        color: "rgb(252, 175, 23)"
      },
      2: {
        type: 'bar',
        targetAxisIndex: 1,
        color: "rgb(0, 103, 174)"
      },
      3: {
        type: 'bar',
        targetAxisIndex: 1,
        color: "rgb(252, 210, 28)"
      },
      4: {
        type: 'line',
        targetAxisIndes: 0,
        color: "rgb(127, 198, 231)"
      },
    },
    isStacked: true
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  var chartLayout;
  var chartBounds;
  var legendColors = [];
  var saveCoords = {};
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function() {
    // init chart elements
    chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    chartBounds = chartLayout.getChartAreaBoundingBox();
    var bars = chart.getContainer().getElementsByTagName('rect');

    // find legend markers
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(bars, function(bar) {

      var color = bar.getAttribute('fill');
      var xCoord = parseFloat(bar.getAttribute('x'));
      var yCoord = parseFloat(bar.getAttribute('y'));
      if ((xCoord >= chartBounds.left) && (yCoord < chartBounds.top) && (color !== '#ffffff')) {
        legendColors.push(color);
      }
    });

    // find bars
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(bars, function(bar, index) {
      var xCoord = parseFloat(bar.getAttribute('x'));
      var yCoord = parseFloat(bar.getAttribute('y'));
      if ((xCoord > chartBounds.left) && (yCoord > chartBounds.top)) {
        var color = bar.getAttribute('fill');
        var width = parseFloat(bar.getAttribute('width')) / 2;
        bar.setAttribute('width', width);
        saveCoords[xCoord + yCoord] = {
          width: width,
          x: xCoord
        };
        if (legendColors.indexOf(color) > 1) {
          bar.setAttribute('x', xCoord + width);
          //ORIGINAL
          //saveCoords[xCoord + yCoord].x = xCoord + width;
          //saveCoords[xCoord + width + yCoord] = saveCoords[xCoord + yCoord];
          //UPDATED
          saveCoords[xCoord + width + yCoord] = {
            width: width,
            x: xCoord + width,
          };
        }
      }
    });

    var observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
      // reset bars
      var bars = chart.getContainer().getElementsByTagName('rect');
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(bars, function(bar, index) {
        var xCoord = parseFloat(bar.getAttribute('x'));
        var yCoord = parseFloat(bar.getAttribute('y'));
        if ((xCoord > chartBounds.left) && (yCoord > chartBounds.top)) {
          var color = bar.getAttribute('fill');
          //ORIGINAL
          //if (saveCoords.hasOwnProperty(xCoord + yCoord)) {
          //  bar.setAttribute('width', saveCoords[xCoord + yCoord].width);
          //  bar.setAttribute('x', saveCoords[xCoord + yCoord].x);
          //}
          //UPDATED
          var width = parseFloat(bar.getAttribute("width")) / 2;
          if (saveCoords.hasOwnProperty(xCoord + width + yCoord)) {
            bar.setAttribute("width", saveCoords[xCoord + width + yCoord].width);
            bar.setAttribute("x", saveCoords[xCoord + width + yCoord].x);
          }
        }
      });
    });
    observer.observe(chart.getContainer(), {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);

  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    chart.draw(data, options);
  });
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: classic charts do not support multiple stacks (`google.visualization.ComboChart`), you would need to use a material bar chart for that (`google.charts.Bar`). however, material charts do not support combo charts, so you wouldn't be able to include the line series using material. check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62290913/5090771) for my attempt to correct multiple stacks using classic chart, though it still needs work...

Comment: Here is an idea worth trying. Maybe multiple stacks are supported accidentally, if you use multiple axes, as you are here. To get the stacks to not overlap, add an extra bar series for each of your current series, but leave it empty or only zero values.  So you would have four series: data1, empty, empty, data2.

Comment: I added a new working example in the post above. I have combined some code for shifting the bars from the suggested post and updated my data to something more actual.  Some of the bars are still missing.